# Error when trying to clear cache with a Symfony2 project

Tags: php, git, symfony, caching

When I try to clear cache:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4304 bytes) in MyProject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 132
```

It happens since my last update. I just added a few changes and I did:

```
git pull

php app/console assets:install web

php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

and then tried to clear cache.

What could I do to solve this?

Comment: `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` doesn't only clear the cache but what kind of assets are you dumping? Are you using minifying somehow? It is sometimes using a lot of resources and can be worth being done on the dev computer and sent to the production server after (for example if you use a cheap vps, you'll probably have this problem...)

Comment: I'm dumping my bundle's files with a few little changes. It has worked for me since a few months ago. I'm minifying js and css files with yui compressor. 15 euros every month is cheap for you?

Comment: Sorry! I had a mistake in the question. The clear cache command was not right. Updated

Comment: Yeah, by cheap I mean small configuration (and this is what I used and I have had the issue before...). Probably worth trying @nifr solution, but if you run out of memory, just run the process on your dev computer and send the output to the server (I know it's a bit painful but that's the only solution I came up with)

Comment: jeah if your vps doesn't have more than `128M` available for PHP you'll probably have to dump your assets locally before deploying and transfer them to your server afterwards.

Comment: @cheesemacfly - As you can see, the problem is the caching process (not dumping). I guess that I can't run this process in my computer instead of the VPS.

Comment: _I just added a few changes and I did_ Revert all your changes until you can clear the cache again. You've changed something which _broke_ the assetic.

Comment: @n.1 - I've tried without success. Seems that I get the same error in a commit where I hadn't before. The thing is that if I clear cache in development mode it works: `php app/console cache:clear`. `Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try to increase your memory limit in the `php.ini` that is used for your CLI ( command line interface ).

Looks like PHP is eating more than the allowed `128M` during the `cache:clear` process.

The directive is `memory_limit` - try:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

You can find your `php.ini` using ...

```
php -i | grep ini       (*nix)
php -i | findstr ini    (windows cmd)
```

... if your cli is using the same `php.ini` as your webapplication - you can aswell create a file with content and access it through your webserver:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

... or probably the easiest way just click the PHP logo in symfony's web toolbar and look out for for `Loaded Configuration File` ( only if cli doesn't use a different `php.ini` ).

Comment: Sorry! I had a mistake in the question. The clear cache command was not right. Updated

Comment: Even increasing until 512M the problem persist.

Comment: some circular reference (i.e in a service definition) might be a cause ... try to disable some bundles one-by-one and try again. Does `cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup` run as expected ?

Comment: `cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup` throws the same error. I just did a few changes on my own bundle, so I don't think that disabling other bundles can help.

Comment: does disabling that bundle prevent that error? did you add some service definitions lately? any custom cache-warmers?

Comment: How can easily disable that bundle to test? Maybe Newrelic is the cause, but I've disabled it (`/etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond stop`) but the error persist.

Comment: Yeah! I was changing `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, while I had to change `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`. When I've put `memory_limit=256M` it has worked right.

Comment: that's why i included **if your cli is using the same php.ini** in my answer :-)

Comment: All right, I thought that adding those lines in the answer it was clearer. But anyway, thank you very much.